# Running PLSQL ( Oracle ) Stored Procedure in Liquibase error : Package or function X is in an invalid state

Tags: oracle, plsql, liquibase

I am trying to run the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE RETRY_TRANS_EXCEPTION
AS
BEGIN
FOR i IN 1..5 LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('Try #' || i);
   ALTER TABLE CIS_CASE ADD TEST01 varchar2(1) NOT NULL;
   END;
END;
/
```

and calling it in changelog.xml as:

> `<sql>CALL RETRY_TRANS_EXCEPTION();</sql>`

i get error:

```
Liquibase update Failed: Migration failed for change set eldata-changelog.xml::2016-08-25-cn-01::Ch Will:Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL CALL RETRY_TRANS_EXCEPTION(): ORA-06575: Package or function RETRY_TRANS_EXCEPTION is in an invalid state
```

What i am trying to achieve is to be able to run a stored procedure through Liquibase with a loop in it.

Thanks for your help Prashant. What worked in my case was your solution plus one change:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE RETRY_TRANS_EXCEPTION
AS
 v_query varchar2(100);
BEGIN
FOR i IN 1..500 LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('Try #' || i);
        v_query := 'ALTER TABLE CIS_CASE ADD TEST01 varchar2(1) NULL';
   execute immediate v_query;
   END loop;
END;
/
```

and then calling the Stored Procedure from the changelog, as:

```
<changeSet id="2016-08-25-cw-01" author="Ch Will">
           <comment>
                        Testing retry logic on liquibase
           </comment>

     <sql>CALL RETRY_TRANS_EXCEPTION();</sql>
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE RETRY_TRANS_EXCEPTION
  2  AS
  3  BEGIN
  4  FOR i IN 1..5 LOOP
  5          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('Try #' || i);
  6     ALTER TABLE CIS_CASE ADD TEST01 varchar2(1) NOT NULL;
  7     END;
  8  END;
  9  /
Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors

SQL> show err
Errors for PROCEDURE PRASHANT-MISHRA.RETRY_TRANS_EXCEPTION:
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6/4      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ALTER" when expecting one of the following:       ( begin case declare end exit for goto if loop mod null     pragma raise return select update while with <an identifier>     <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<     continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback     savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
```

Did required fixes :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE RETRY_TRANS_EXCEPTION
AS
 v_query varchar2(100);
BEGIN
FOR i IN 1..5 LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('Try #' || i);
        v_query := 'ALTER TABLE CIS_CASE ADD TEST01 varchar2(1) NOT NULL' ;
   execute immediate v_query;
   END loop;
END;
```

Comment: not sure why i am getting error: Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL CALL RETRY_TRANS_EXCEPTION(): ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name

Answer (score 3):

You can't call it because the procedure does not compile correctly.  Go back and fix the compilation errors, then try again.

Here are a couple of errors that stand out to me:

1. the `for` loop should end with `end loop;`, not `end;`
2. You can't have DDL statements directly in the code. You need dynamic SQL to execute a DDL statement from a procedure: `execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE CIS_CASE ADD TEST01 varchar2(1) NOT NULL';`

Additional note: I don't understand why you are trying to execute the same DDL statement multiple times inside a loop. Obviously, you won't be able to add the same column with the same name over and over.  You will get a runtime error.

Comment: Excuse my shortcoming with SQL and Stored Procedures. What i am trying to achieve is to make sure a SQL statement executes as due to the sheer volume of data, if i am able to try N number of times, it is guaranteed to execute eventually ( might not be the best way to achieve that )

Answer (score 0):

PLSQL stored procedure can't use DDL statements, like

```
alter table ...
```

so the

```
execute immediate ("...")
```

statement is  required because in fact it creates an autonomous implicit transition that can't be rollbacked